# hide/offset WOW js animations when delayed

Tags: jquery, css, animation, wow.js

I'm using [WOW](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/index.html) to animate different divs on my web page. However I am delaying some of the divs, which means you can see them just sitting slightly off the screen until the delay kicks in, then the transition happens. You can see an example of this [here](http://www.meganhutchinson.co.uk/aat/idea.html).

From the examples [here](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/index.html) the animated divs are hidden and then they animate in, I dont understand how to achieve the same thing? As I have followed their [docs](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html) and there's no difference from what I can see.

Any help on how to achieve this same effect would be brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply same thing using "data-wow-delay" attribute example :-

```
<div class="wow slideInRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s"></div>
<div class="wow slideInLeft" data-wow-delay="1.0s"></div>
<div class="wow slideInRight" data-wow-delay="2.0s"></div>
```

using "data-wow-delay" attribute throw you can achieve load div in different time.